# Can't get list of files using PathMatcher and regex

Tags: java, regex, file, match, wildcard

I'm using PathMatcher and SimpleFileVisitor to iterate over directory and find all the files that start only with a certain prefix. However, I can't get any files although there are some files that match my preference.

Example of file required:

```
Prefix_some_text.csv
```

Here is the Main code that invokes the call for SimpleFileVisitor class, and it uses regex pattern with the prefix and suppose to find all files starting with the certain pattern:

```
String directoryAsString = "C:/Users";
String pattern = "Prefix";
SearchFileByWildcard sfbw = new SearchFileByWildcard();
        try {
            List<String> actual = sfbw.searchWithWc(Paths.get(directoryAsString),pattern);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The implementation of SearchFileByWildcard  class that uses SimpleFileVisitor :

```
static class SearchFileByWildcard {
    List<String> matchesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> searchWithWc(Path rootDir, String pattern) throws IOException {
        matchesList.clear();
        FileVisitor<Path> matcherVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attribs) throws IOException {
                FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
                PathMatcher matcher = fs.getPathMatcher("regex:" + pattern);
                Path name = file.getFileName(); //takes the filename from the full path
                if (matcher.matches(name)) {
                    matchesList.add(name.toString());
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        };
        Files.walkFileTree(rootDir, matcherVisitor);
        return matchesList;
    }
}
```

I'm debating whether to use glob instead of regex? Or maybe something with my regex is flawed.

Comment: Glob != regex pattern. Obviously a regex is much more powerful though. What *is* the pattern?

Comment: I need to find any file with specific pattern given by user. In my specific example the file starts  with the word Prefix. So I'm finding each file that start with it. I want a generic way to use it, that the pattern will be dynamic, because maybe sometimes the pattern is at the end of file? or in the middle?

Comment: Unless your users are very 'techie' they are less likely to get it wrong with a glob than a regex. Of course, you could parameterize the type of search too, with the default being glob but regex an 'advanced' option

Comment: How can I use pattern using glob? All I see are examples that find file extensions or by a pattern of specific directories, but not on the filename alone.

Comment: Try `glob:Prefix*`

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped, replaced the regex with glob and added *

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the pattern is wrong. It matches only files named "Prefix". Try to change it in `String pattern = "Prefix.*";`.

Otherwise you can scan for files which name starts by the string "Prefix".

```
String name = file.getFileName().toString();
if (name.startsWith(pattern)) {
    matchesList.add(name);
}
```

Comment: *It matches only files named "Pattern".* Actually, no. It matches only paths called *exactly* "Prefix". Your suggested pattern is correct though

Comment: Just a thought as a more generic way, what if the pattern given by user is to search for files that ends with the pattern, or the file contains the pattern?